# How to copy several not-subfolders in one shot?

Tags: command-line, cp

Assume my current path is `/home/inp/Documents/Folder`
I would like to copy folders `/home/inp/Test1/randomName1` and `/home/inp/Test1/randomName2` from my current path.
Currently, I use the following command:

```
cp ~/Test1/randomName1 ~/Test1/randomName2 .
```

Is it possible to combine `randomName1` and `randomName2` without using regular expression? Something like:

```
cp ~Test1/[randomName2,randomName2] .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with brace expansion:

```
cp ~Test1/{randomName1,randomName2} .
```

This will expand to each string in the braces:

```
$ echo Something{1,2,3,5}
Something1 Something2 Something3 Something5
```

**or**

```
cp ~Test1/randomName{1..2} .
```

This will expand to each number between the start and end, and can also be used with single letters:

```
$ echo Something{1..5}
Something1 Something2 Something3 Something4 Something5
$ echo Something{a..e}
Somethinga Somethingb Somethingc Somethingd Somethinge
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not I want because randomName1 and randomName2 are really random, for example 'tortue' and 'ninja'. In this case, I cannot use regular expressions.

Comment: So glob.  `cp /path/to/src/* /path/to/dest/`

Comment: Excuse me, I have the answer! I just write cp ~/Test1/{tortue,ninja} Thank you!

Comment: @DopeGhoti Not good when there is a lot of other folders.